creating a bootable USB drive with a single partition
I want to install Debian in dual boot with Windows, for this I created a bootable USB key under Linux Lite (Ubuntu based distro), with the #dd command.
The command I used is:
dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M status=progress && syn
At the time of installation I noticed that this iso file does not have the wifi firmware, I know after research that Debian has a non_free iso file, which means that it has non-free firmware ...
But the Debian site also offers a second method, and for learning reasons, I wanted to test the second, the second method is to inject firmware that I have already downloaded from the official site into the firmware folder of the USB key which is on the root.
The problem is that the dd command created a partition of the exact size of the iso file! with iso9660 format! the rest of the USB key is an unallocated partition.
i did the same test on windows with rufus and everything works fine, refusal to create a partition equal to the total size of the USB key, so i was able to inject files without problems!
my question is, how to create a bootable USB key on linux in command line with, for example the dd command or another, which would allow me to add a file after creation

If UEFI system, you can create a FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags. Most systems prefer gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. Then you can extract ISO into the FAT32 partition. I used 7zip. Have not done it for a while as I normally use grub to loopmount ISOs. sudo 7z x ~/ISO/impish-desktop-canary-amd64.iso -o/media/fred/EFI_SSD64 My old command as example. Does not work on Windows as it has .wim file over 4GB that needs split. Most should otherwise work. Note no space after -o.

thank you @oldfred , I tried your suggestion , it work for efi system, what can I do for msdos (MBR) table partition , there is a solution , my goal is to learne differente things

I always preferred to have separate flash drives for BIOS/MBR and UEFI/gpt back when I still wanted a BIOS install. Some installed grub BIOS boot version grub-pc to MBR. But sometimes updates would get systems out of sync. Since 2012 systems are UEFI, so not much use for BIOS/MBR anymore. Grub will boot in BIOS mode from gpt drive if you add a tiny 1MB unformatted partition wth bios_grub flag or ef02 using gdisk. The only place for MBR is Windows boot in BIOS mode.

see man fdisk & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step
